# Signed integer to two's complement hexadecimal

Tags: python, hex, twos-complement

I have written a function in Python to take a signed integer, convert it using two's Complement then return the hexadecimal value. I know there is a `hex()` function, but I want to be able to specify the size of the integer. How could I improve the quality of this code  and have I missed anything? Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

int8, int16, int32, int64 = 8, 16, 32, 64

def intToHexString(value, bits):
  def getBitmask(bits):
    mask = 0
    for i in range(bits):
      mask = (mask << 1) + 1
    return mask

  if not isinstance(value, (int, long)):
    raise ValueError("'%s' is not an Integer!"%str(value))
  if not isinstance(bits, int) or bits % 2 != 0:
    raise ValueError("Illegal integer size," +
      "value %s must be divisible by 2!"%str(bits))
  result = value
  bitmask = getBitmask(bits)
  halfMask = bitmask >> 1
  minVal, maxVal = -halfMask, halfMask-1
  if not minVal <= result <= maxVal:
    raise ValueError('Out of range: %d <= %d <= %d'
      %(minVal, result, maxVal))
  if value < 0:
    result = ((abs(value) ^ bitmask) + 1) & bitmask
  return '%0*X'%(int(float(bits)/4), result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x, y = 280, -54
  print intToHexString(x, int16), intToHexString(y, int8)
```

This code should return the values `0118` and `CA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write it more like this:

```
def int_to_hex_string(value, bits):
    return "{0:0{1}X}".format(value & ((1<<bits) - 1), bits//4)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  x, y = 280, -54
  print(int_to_hex_string(x, 16), int_to_hex_string(y, 8))
```

I don't think your type checks add anything: if the values aren't of the correct types you'll get a more appropriate 'TypeError' by not checking, likewise the 'int16' and 'int8' as aliases for 16 and 8 don't really add much.

Comment: Almost perfect, but you want `X` not `x` in the format, so the OP gets `CA` not `ca` in the output.

Comment: Comment to the OP: Even if you want an error with a nicer message so it doesn't say something about `unsupported types for <<` (leaving the user to wonder "when did I try to use `<<`?)… you probably want to do that by catching an exception and raising a new one (ideally using PEP 3134 chaining), instead of pre-checking. And use `TypeError` rather than `ValueError`.

Comment: One last thing: The OP is using Python 2.x, so your `print` is going to print a tuple.

Comment: I'm assuming he can add a `from __future__` import if he needs one.

Comment: I like the Python3 constructs that you used. Yeah, I could use `__future__`. I am using Python 2.7.3.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: If you like Python3 constructs, have you considered installing 3.3.1 and using that instead of 2.7.3? Sometimes there are good reasons to stick with 2.7 (maintaining legacy code that you don't have time to port, need PyPy/Jython/Iron, need a module that hasn't been updated yet, learning from an ancient book/tutorial whose code barely runs in 2.7 much less 3.x, …), but otherwise…

Comment: I considered it. After watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_6vDi7ywuA) I think I will download it.